# Unable to set value outside of mvc public class even after calling and assign value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class call InnerItem where I want to preset the value to 50 and 100 to SubTotal and Total respectively. Then I call the class to an actionresult to change it before display ,but I'm unable to change the values to another set of values. Is there anything that I have miss out?

Sample Code - Simplify Version.

Model

```
public class InnerItem
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
}
public class OuterItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ModelNo { get; set; }
    private InnerItem _details;
    public InnerItem Display
    {
        get {
            _details = new InnerItem();
            _details.Total = 100;
            _details.Subtotal = 50;
            return _details;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult DisplayDetail()
{
    OuterItem DisplayStuff = new OuterItem();
    DisplayStuff.Name = "JOHN";
    DisplayStuff.ModelNo = "FERRARI001";
    DisplayStuff.Display.Subtotal = 10000;
    DisplayStuff.Display.Total = 20000;

    return PartialView(DisplayStuff);
}
```

Output

```
DisplayStuff.Name = "JOHN";
DisplayStuff.ModelNo = "FERRARI001";
DisplayStuff.Display.Subtotal = 100;
DisplayStuff.Display.Total = 50;
```

Comment: I might be wrong here but don't you need a set for the inner? Also you're creating a new one every time.

Comment: it compile without error. but wont the set automatically set itself?

Comment: You are lacking a basic understanding of C# properties and fields.

Comment: yes you are right. i just started learning myself. taking in sample from everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you access `Display` property, you are returning a `new InnerItem`

```
// This creates a new .Display
DisplayStuff.Display.Subtotal = 10000;

// And now this creates a new .Display too
DisplayStuff.Display.Total = 20000;
```

Perhaps you want this:

```
public InnerItem Display
{
    get {
        if (_details == null)
        {
            _details = new InnerItem();
            _details.Total = 100;
            _details.Subtotal = 50;
        }
        return _details;
    }
}
```

Meaning: only create the `_details` once, the first time it is accessed.

Comment: yes... can be an option, but just in case of single thread environment.

Comment: sorry do you mind elaborating on the term single thread environment

Comment: he means that there is no locking on the `Display` property. Which for your MVC should be totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Lazy<InnerItem> _details = new Lazy<Details>(() => new InnerItem {/*use some default initialization here if you need*/} ); 
public InnerItem Display
{
   get {
       return _details.Value;
   }
}
```